# Memory increases drastically when I type in a UITextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uitextfield

This is how I have created two textfields in a tableview and i release them in the dealloc method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 300, 30)];
        text.delegate=self;
        text.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        text.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        if ( qNum-1 == 53 ) {
            text.placeholder=@"Category";
        }
        [cell.contentView addSubview:text];
    }
    if ([indexPath row] == 1) {
        text2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 300, 30)];
        text2.delegate=self;
        text2.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        if(qNum-1==53) {
            text2.placeholder=@"Subcategory";
        }
        text2.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:text2];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is as soon as the virtual keyboard appears and i start typing into the textfields the memory increases drastically. Can someone please help me out of this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I have written inside the delegate methods

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
```

}

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

if([text.text isEqualToString:@"United States"]||[text.text isEqualToString:@"Australia"]){
    text2.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    item.title=@"State";
    myPickerView.hidden=YES;
    myPickerView2.hidden=NO;
    [actionSheet showInView:mainView];
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
}
```

}

Comment: I think your problem is in the text field delegate methods. Please post that code and please format it while posting. That will make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems. You are adding new `UITextFields` to your cell, even when reusing it, so you add new text fields over and over to the same cell. You need to build distinct setup logic for the different types of cells *within* the `if (cell == nil)` part, and only configure these cells later. Also, you probably want to release the text fields after adding them as a subview. Please refer to the examples in Apple's documentation for `UITableView`.

You might want to show your delegate methods - maybe there are some more problems.

Comment: +1 There is a definite possibility of leaks in the delegate methods but this method has enough of its own.

Comment: I have tried writing the code within the block u have mentioned and released the textfields. But still the memory is shooting up when i start typing. Please help me out of this!

Comment: The delegate methods look ok. When reworking your cell creation, you want to make the cell identifier dependent on the type of cell. But for deeper analysis, we need much more information.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:text];   
[text release];
```

and

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:text2];
[text2 release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip . But still no use !

Answer (score 0):

You are not releasing textfields

Comment: I have tried  releasing the textfields. But still the memory condition remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Instruments to detect memory allocation? I've noticed the same exact problem. Memory usage just shoots up when the keyboard shows up... I think it's something you don't have to worry about. There's nothing I did that fixed this, and it pretty much happens in every instance when the keyboard appears. Probably a bug of Instruments?